# generation of dummy variable for bubble in exuber package

Tags: finance, exuberant-ctags

I want to create dummy variable for bubble after i used radf function of exuber package on the financial data series. how to do that? I have a weekly data of usa stock market S&P 500 index for the period of thirty years.

i need a code on this.